# How to get genotype data of SNVs from several new bam files?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, genome, vcf-variant-call-format

I have several SNVs:

```
#CHROM  POS ID REF ALT
chr1   1000  .   A   C
chr1   2000  .   T   A
```

Can I get their genotype data (REF coverage, ALT coverage) from some new bam files? for example, bam files from 2 tumor samples:

```
tumor1.bam
tumor2.bam
```

I expect a VCF format result like below, other formats work too.

```
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DR,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of reference reads">
##FORMAT=<ID=DV,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of variant reads">
#CHROM  POS ID REF ALT  FORMAT   tumor1.bam tumor2.bam
chr1   1000  .   A   C  GT:DR:DV  0/1:20:10   0/1:30:5
chr1   2000  .   T   A  GT:DR:DV  0/1:80:10   0/1:20:8
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why using python when you can can the variant with any caller ?  e.g:  https://www.htslib.org/workflow/wgs-call.html ( or use a system call ?)

Comment: @Pierre Hi, thanks for the comment. The variant has been called and VCF files were generated. The question now is if I can get genotypes of these sites from other bam files. For example, I find a variant in one person, and I would like to know if it exits in other people without calling variants in other people again.

Comment: just call the given position(s) for the other bams ?

Comment: @Pierre which tool are you talking about? I don't know any tools can do that.

Comment: I'm talking about the samtools/bcftools workflow above, but it could be gatk too. For example bcftools mpileup has an option --regions-file where you can put your positions...

Comment: @Pierre bcftools mpileup is what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pierre, one solution to this question was found.

**bcftools mpileup** can output genotypes in a vcf format:

```
bcftools mpileup -f ref.fa -R input.vcf tumor1.bam tumor2.bam -a FORMAT/AD
```

The output will be like this:

```
##FORMAT=<ID=PL,Number=G,Type=Integer,Description="List of Phred-scaled genotype likelihoods">
##FORMAT=<ID=AD,Number=R,Type=Integer,Description="Allelic depths (high-quality bases)">
#CHROM  POS ID REF     ALT  FORMAT    tumor1.bam   tumor2.bam
chr1   1000  .   A   C,<*>   PL:AD    xx:20,10,0    xx:30,5,0
chr1   2000  .   T   A,<*>   PL:AD    xx:80,10,0    xx:20,8,0
```

Comment: bctools mpileup should be followed by bcftools call. Read the doc.

Comment: @Pierre Yes, bcftools call will do some filtering base on genotype likelihoods. But if the count of all reads (including possible tech errors) is need, then bcftools mpileup result is a better choice.